# Access SMB Fileshare via edge runtime module ( without blob storage module )

Tags: azure-iot-edge

I am facing a scenario where I have to access the images from SMB file share through application deployed as edge runtime module.  I have gone through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-store-data-blob#using-smb-share-as-your-local-storage, But that talks via blob module which is not the way I want to go due to some agreed decisions.

Is it possible to access the fileshare via edge runtime module (application).

One of the workaround I see is : Deploy a custom .NET Core Edge-module on a Linux VM tried to read files on a Windows File-share in same VNet and Azure file-share using it...

1. Mount the fileshare (both windows & azure) on the host using smb protocol
2. Read it from the container by mapping the mount point to a containers file system.

Just need to understand if this is the correct way, any known challenges or limitation in this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I don't expect any issues or limitations doing like you said.

You will just not be able to leverage Azure Blob Storage functionalities on your IoT Edge nor Azure storage SDK methods or blob API calls.